# Xamarin Linker - App crashes unless Linker is set to "Don't Link" but IPA is too big for App Store

Tags: xamarin, linker, preserve

Our Xamarin app will crash unless the linker is set to "Don't link" - however this creates an archive that is too big for the app store/TestFlight limits.  We use the Microsoft.Azure.cosmos NuGet package and the linker seems to be removing it on the build when "Link SDK's only" is selected. How can I tell the linker not to remove since I can't edit the 3rd party assembly itself?  All items that I have found regarding preserving linking behavior seem to involve adding code to the assembly itself, which is not an option here.

Thank you!!!

Comment: the official Linker docs explicitly cover this scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#skipping-assemblies

Comment: Thanks Jason - I have reviewed but adding --linkskip=Microsoft.Azure.cosmos does not seem to change the linker behavior

Comment: you need to specify the name of the assemblies, not the nuget package

Comment: yes, assemblies are dlls

Comment: I think "nolinkaway" is what I needed, and not "linkskip" - appreciate your responses Jason!

Answer (score 0):

Per Jason, use the Linker [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#skipping-assemblies).  The subtle difference between nolinkaway and linkskip is what I was missing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).